# .NET MAUI BLE Download Speed Slows During Download

Tags: c#, macos, bluetooth-lowenergy, maui

I have a BLE sensor which records data every few seconds and am downloading the records to my Mac.

I used .NET MAUI to create a desktop application which downloads the data using the CoreBluetooth libraries. However, during download, the first ~1200 records download in 20 seconds before slowing to ~500 records a minute. This is in contrast to tools we have written on other platforms, which maintain up to ~5000 record per minute download speeds.

I used CBCentralManager with a custom serialized dispatch queue to scan for the BLE devices and, once found, use the CBPeripheralDelegate "UpdatedCharacteristicValue" callback to download the data after connecting.

I tried removing all application processing code, just discarding messages after read, but the problem persists, suggesting this isn't an application level issue. In addition, because the download speed starts at the correct speed, this suggests BLE settings like MTU are set correctly. I also ensured write without response is enabled on the connection.

Are there any underlying buffers or storage which need to be cleared when using BluetoothCore on .NET MAUI on a Mac, or other reasons download speed might suddenly drop off? Or is this some hardware limitation on the Mac itself?

Link to minimal example, code is to large to try and add here: https://github.com/Branden22/BLE_Download_Sample

Comment: Add relevant code to question. Maybe link to a repo containing enough code to reproduce the problem. Slowdown makes me think something is “piling up” somewhere. Maybe download code interfering with something else that needs to run? Some event handler falling behind? Or getting duplicated. As a test, what happens if you do `await Task.Delay(10);` after each record? What I’m looking to see is whether the performance stays consistent, if you relinquish cpu after each record.

Comment: Sending lots of data via BLE may cause the antenna to heat up, which can result in lower data rates. So, either the data isn't processed fast enough as Steve wrote, or the hardware cannot handle it without overheating. Generally, iOS and macOS are pretty restrictive with regards to BLE from my experience.

Comment: Tried adding await Task.Delay(10) but I get the same results. Added a minimal example. Hardware overheating seems possible, though I would expect less consistency in the error. Is there some way to verify this would be the problem?